# Conditional execution of a method using annotation

Tags: java, annotations, conditional-execution

In java can I have conditional execution of a method using annotations?

I wish to have some system property set and based on that system property I wish to either execute or not execute a method (specifically ant script based JUnits) at runtime.

Please let me know if it's possible using the annotations.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question: Are you looking for ways to enable/ disable JUnit test depending of some system properties?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can implement it in Java but I suggest you to take a look on [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) - I believe that this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can group tests by @Category and tell the running to include this category.

From http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=1711

```
public interface FastTests { /* category marker */ }
public interface SlowTests { /* category marker */ }

public class A {
    @Category(SlowTests.class)
    @Test public void a() {}
}

@Category(FastTests.class})
public class B {
    @Test public void b() {}
}

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(SlowTests.class)
@ExcludeCategory(FastTests.class)
@SuiteClasses({ A.class, B.class })
public class SlowTestSuite {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own [TestRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html) or user [AOP](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

An annotation, in the Java computer programming language, is a form of syntactic metadata that can be added to Java source code. Classes, methods, variables, parameters and packages may be annotated.

Take a look at [this](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/java/creating-custom-annotations-and-making-use-of-them/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a simple custom test runner by extending [`BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html). That runner would read a configuration from a system property or a configuration file to only run the defined tests. The simplest solution would be a blacklist to exclude selected methods, because the default behaviour of this (default!) runner is to run every test.

Then just say

```
@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)
public void TestClass {

// ...

}
```

For the implementation, it could be sufficiant to just overwrite the `getChildren()` method:

```
@Overwrite
List<FrameworkMethod> getChildren() {
    List<FrameworkMethod> fromParent = super.getChildren();
    List<FrameworkMethod> filteredList = new ArrayList(filter(fromParent));
    return filteredList;
}
```

where filter checks for every `FrameworkMethod` whether it should be executed or not according to the "blacklist", that has been created based on the property.